# Getting an exception when trying to use extension method with SortedDictionary... why?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison

I'm trying to place custom objects into a sorted dictionary...  I am then trying to use an extension method (Max()) on this sorted dictionary.  However, I'm getting the exception: "At least one object must implement IComparable".  I don't understand why I'm getting that, as my custom object obviously implements IComparable.  Here is my code:

```
public class MyDate : IComparable<MyDate>
{
    int IComparable<MyDate>.CompareTo(MyDate obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (this.Value.Ticks < obj.Value.Ticks)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else if (this.Value.Ticks == obj.Value.Ticks)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    public MyDate(DateTime date)
    {
        this.Value = date;
    }

    public DateTime Value;
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SortedDictionary<MyDate, int> sd = new SortedDictionary<MyDate,int>();

        sd.Add(new MyDate(new DateTime(1)), 1);
        sd.Add(new MyDate(new DateTime(2)), 2);

       Console.WriteLine(sd.Max().Value);   // Throws exception!!  
    }
}
```

What on earth am I doing wrong???

Comment: `Max()` extension operates on types of `IEnumerable<T>`. what is `SortedDictionary<T,U>` an `IEnumerable<T>` of? i bet it's not what you think ... [spoiler alert!] `SortedDictionary<T,U>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValue<T,U>>`! and `KeyValue<T,U>` does not support `IComparable`!

Comment: Argh why the $%@# is that method even there then??  How am I supposed to use freaking Max() in relation to SortedDictionary if this is incorrect?

Comment: Because `Dictionary` implements `IEnumerable`. So it’s entirely reasonable for the method to be there. Unfortunately, C# lacks the ability to discriminate generic parameter specializations (unlike e.g. C++), otherwise `Max` could indeed be made to miss from objects of the wrong item type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because this is not trying to compare your custom objects, but instances of KeyValuePair.

This should work

```
Console.WriteLine(sd.Last().Value);
```

Because the sorted dictionary is sorted, the last item is the largest assuming the comparer is comparing smallest to largest.

Comment: Chris, is calling .Last() or .First() an O(N) operation??  I wouldn't think it is, but I just want to be sure :)

Comment: @Polaris878, .Last() will be O(n) for SortedDictionary because it will enumerate all the elements using an in-order traversal of the tree to get to the last item. However if you have the dictionary sorted in reverse then you can use .First() which is O(log n) operation.